# Spring MappingJacksonJsonView, how to tell to use it instead of JSP view?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use `MappingJacksonJsonView` with Spring 3.0, without success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think the problem is that I don't know how to tell to use the `MappingJacksonJsonView` to render a request. I tried to use the same name for view name and bean name of `MappingJacksonView`, but didn't work. I built a sample test application here: https://github.com/stivlo/restjson

In [web.xml](https://github.com/stivlo/restjson/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) I've defined `ContextLoaderListener` and the mapping for `dispatcherServlet`.

In [servlet-context.xml](https://github.com/stivlo/restjson/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml) I've added

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

and

```
<bean name="jsonView"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
```

In [org.obliquid.restjson.web.ToDoList.java](https://github.com/stivlo/restjson/blob/master/src/main/java/org/obliquid/restjson/web/ToDoList.java) I set the logical view name as `jsonView`.

However, instead of using `MappingJacksonJsonView`, it looks for a JSP file, according to my JSP mapping.

```
message /restjson/WEB-INF/jsp/jsonView.jsp
description The requested resource (/restjson/WEB-INF/jsp/jsonView.jsp) 
    is not available.
```

What should I change to use `MappingJacksonJsonView` as a renderer?

**UPDATE 1**: In following tests I've found that if I add the following to my servlet-context.xml, JSON rendering works, but my other view, rendered as JSP (home) is not working anymore.

```
<!-- Resolve views based on string names -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
```

**UPDATE 2**: I removed the `BeanNameViewResolver` and changed my ToDoList.java to return directly the Collection to be converted in JSON, instead of ModelAndView, with a `@ResponseBody` annotation, as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/toDoList")
public @ResponseBody List<ToDoItem> test() {
    List<ToDoItem> toDoList = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();        
    toDoList.add(new ToDoItem(1, "First thing, first"));
    toDoList.add(new ToDoItem(1, "After that, do the second task"));
    return toDoList;
}
```

In this way it works. Even though the mapping is even more "magical". It makes me wonder, if a similar renderer exists for XML for instance, how does Spring know which renderer to pick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring will use `Accept` header sent by the client to return most appropriate view. [Here](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/books) you will find my complete Spring MVC application that returns both JSON and XML.

As you can see, I only needed:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I also used the same annotations: `@RequestMapping` to map request to a method and `@ResponseBody` to tell Spring that what I am returning from the controller is the actual response. It might however need some tweaking/formatting, and here Spring takes care of marshalling your object into most appropriate type like JSON.

Comment: Thank you, now I try and look at your app.

Comment: If anyone is interested in a full showcase implementation of a REST service with jQuery interface I recommend reading Tomasz' blog article at http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/07/poor-mans-crud-jqgrid-rest-ajax-and.html

Answer (score 2):

You should do it this way:

In your xml file set the following: set

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

After it you need to set Jackson serializer:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

after it you can use it in your Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getObjects",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
     public  List<MyObject> getCategories(){
     List<MyObject> objects = daoService.gettAllObjects();
     return objects;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following worked in my case

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

So basically we should try to resolve any view as a bean first

Answer (score 0):

you will need to see **ContentNegotiatingViewResolver**,and set **defaultviews** property to **MappingJacksonJsonView**, and @ResponseBody uses  HttpMessageConverter to instead of ViewSolver,see the differences between them
http://ufasoli.blogspot.com/2013/08/viewresolver-vs-messageconverter-spring.html