# .getJSON 404 Error with ModelAndView

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to retrieve some JSON data in my javascript by making a call to the controller. The controller returns a MappingJacksonJsonView ModelandView, but the .getJSON is always reporting a 404 at .../handhygiene.json.

Is there a problem with the way I am returning the ModelandView from the controller?

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{room}/handhygiene.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getHandHygienePageAsync(
    @PathVariable(value = "room") String roomCode) {
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MappingJacksonJsonView());
mav.getModelMap().addAttribute(blahblahblah); //adds some attributes
...

return mav;
}
```

Javascript

```
var currentURL = window.location;
$.getJSON(currentURL + ".json",
    function(data) {
    ... //does stuff with data
}
```

Comment: HTTP 404 is ... not found.

Comment: The .getJSON call is successfully reaching the controller, which returns a modelandview. The question I have is why is the returned modelandview object resulting in a 404? (It reaches the controller but not the function(data){} part of the javascript.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get only an JSON object from Ajax request, you need to add `@ResponseBody` to your method, and make you result object as return from your method.

The @ResponseBody tells to Spring that he need to serialize your object to return to the client as content-type. By default, Spring uses JSON Serialization. ModelAndView will try to return an .JSP page. Maybe you don't have this jsp page on your resources so, the server return 404 error.

I Think this code should work for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{room}/handhygiene.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Room getHandHygienePageAsync(@PathVariable(value = "room") String roomCode) {
    Room room = myService.findRoomByRoomCode(roomCode);
    return room;
}
```

I'm assuming you're using the Room as your result object, but it may be another object or ArrayList, for example.

You cant take a look [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) for Spring example, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794974/spring-mappingjacksonjsonview-how-to-tell-to-use-it-instead-of-jsp-view) for example and configuration.